# uninstall tata photon plus

Tags: software-uninstall

I have installed tata photon plus modem previously. Now I don't want to use it.

I tried to uninstall, when I click on "**uninstall photon plus**" in dash its appearing "**You must run the process by root**".

I tried already with these 2 commands, showing some error messages

```
sudo apt-get remove photon
sudo apt-get purge photon
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the output of `grep -Ri 'uninstall photon plus' /usr/share/applications`.

Comment: there is no result for `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep photon`

Comment: ramesh@ramesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ grep -Ri 'uninstall photon plus' /usr/share/applications

/usr/share/applications/UninstallMobilePartner.desktop:Comment=Uninstall Photon Plus

/usr/share/applications/UninstallMobilePartner.desktop:Comment[en]=Uninstall Photon Plus

/usr/share/applications/UninstallMobilePartner.desktop:Name=Uninstall Photon Plus

/usr/share/applications/UninstallMobilePartner.desktop:Name[en]=Uninstall Photon Plus

Comment: how did you install tata photon plus?

Comment: first inserted photon plus modem than opened in terminal.

Comment: installed by using "./INSTALL" command

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem, follow the following steps to reach the solution:

1. Open Terminal, change directory `cd /usr/share/applications/`
2. Open the file `vi UninstallMobilePartner.desktop`
3. Find the path for `EXEC`
4. Change that path possibly to `/usr/local/Photon`
5. Run `sudo ./UnistallMobilePartner`

This will uninstall Photon + GUI from from Ubuntu workstation.